# Contact Form 7 or Customize Form

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I need to implement a heavy form, but I don`t know which is better: CF7 or customize variant?
The disadvantage of implementation the form in CF7 is that there is a lot of html code in admin, but I don't want that.

Comment: Refer this. Hope this will helps you https://youtu.be/PBHqArTEBSM.

Answer (score 0):

Use Quick contact form. 
This helps you to nearly eliminate all the writing of html.
And it will help you for heavy forms